# Which script can be used to finetune BERT for SQuAD question answering in Hugging Face library?

Tags: bert, huggingface, question-answering

I have gone through lot of blogs which talk about `run_squad.py` script from Hugging Face, but I could not find it in the latest repo. So, which script has to be used now for fine tuning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [recent PR](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/pull/9010) changed the location of the scripts you are looking for to [`examples/legacy/question-answering`](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/tree/master/examples/legacy/question-answering)

Comment: thanks for pointing out , since the scripts are moved to legacy , is the one below latest script, https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/master/examples/question-answering/run_qa.py